# Deploying Flask API in AWS throws error No Module named 'app'. When app is in my root directory

Tags: python, git, flask, aws-lambda, gitlab-ci.yml

I am deploying a flask API in AWS using a lambda package.

The code runs fine locally on my windows machine in a virtual environment wth the same library version as available in the Lambda.

When deployed, the deployment is successful with no compilation errors, but when the API is triggered, it throws an error.

In watchLogs the error is:
`Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app': No module named '_brotli'`

This is my file structure:

```
`bin:
  app.py
  .gitlab-ci.yml
  requirements.txt
  utils
  routes
  models
  serializers`
```

This is a part of my ci/cd file:

```
`build:cam-service-functions:  
  stage: package  
  image: python:3.8  
  tags:  
    - AWS  
  script:  
    - apt-get -y install zip  
    - pip install -r ./requirements.txt -t ./venv --no-input --exists-action w  
    - cd venv  
    - zip -r9 ../cam.zip .  
    - cd ..  
    - zip -ur cam.zip  *.* routes models serializers utils  
    - zip -d cam.zip typing_extensions.py    
    - du -sh cam.zip     
 artifacts:  
 paths:  
    - ./cam.zip  
 expire_in: 1 week `
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried changing library version, tinkering with the cicd file, nothing worked